# Am I using LMDB incorrectly? It says environment mapsize limit reached after 0 insertions

Tags: python, database, machine-learning, lmdb

I am trying to create an LMDB database for my Caffe machine learning project. But LMDB throws an error ont the first attempt to insert a data point, saying the environment mapsize is full.

Here's the code that attempts to populate the database:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os
import lmdb
import random
# my data structure for holding image/label pairs
from serialization import DataPoint

class LoadImages(object):
    def __init__(self, image_data_path):
        self.image_data_path = image_data_path
        self.dirlist = os.listdir(image_data_path)

        # find the number of images that are to be read from disk
        # in this case there are 370 images.
        num = len(self.dirlist)

        # shuffle the list of image files so that they are read in a random order
        random.shuffle(self.dirlist)

        map_size = num*10

        j=0

        # load images from disk
        for image_filename in os.listdir(image_data_path):
            # check that every image belongs to either category _D_ or _P_
            assert (image_filename[:3] == '_D_' or image_filename[:3] == '_P_'), "ERROR: unknown category"

            # set up the LMDB datbase object
            env = lmdb.open('image_lmdb', map_size=map_size)
            with env.begin(write=True) as txn:

                # iterate over (shuffled) list of image files
                for image_filename in self.dirlist:
                    print "Loading " + str(j) + "th image from disk - percentage complete:  " + str((float(j)/num) * 100) + " %"

                    # open the image
                    with open(str(image_data_path + "/" + image_filename), 'rb') as f:
                        image = Image.open(f)
                        npimage = np.asarray(image, dtype=np.float64)

                    # discard alpha channel, if necessary
                    if npimage.shape[2] == 4:
                        npimage = npimage[:,:,:3]
                        print image_filename + " had its alpha channel removed."

                    # get category
                    if image_filename[:3] == '_D_':
                        category = 0
                    elif image_filename[:3] == '_P_':
                        category = 1

                    # wrap image data and label into a serializable data structure
                    datapoint = DataPoint(npimage, category)
                    serialized_datapoint = datapoint.serialize()

                    # a database key
                    str_id = '{:08}'.format(j)

                    # put the data point in the LMDB
                    txn.put(str_id.encode('ascii'), serialized_datapoint)

                j+=1
```

I also made a little data structure to hold images and labels and serialize them, which is used above:

```
import numpy as np

class DataPoint(object):
    def __init__(self, image=None, label=None, dtype=np.float64):
        self.image = image
        if self.image is not None:
            self.image = self.image.astype(dtype)
        self.label = label

    def serialize(self):
        image_string = self.image.tobytes()
        label_string = chr(self.label)
        datum_string = label_string + image_string
        return datum_string

    def deserialize(self, string):
        image_string = string[1:]
        label_string = string[:1]
        image = np.fromstring(image_string, dtype=np.float64)
        label = ord(label_string)
        return DataPoint(image, label)
```

Here's the error:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/hal9000/PycharmProjects/Caffe_Experiments_0.6/gather_images.py
Loading 0th image from disk - percentage complete:  0.0 %
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hal9000/PycharmProjects/Caffe_Experiments_0.6/gather_images.py", line 69, in <module>
    g = LoadImages(path)
  File "/home/hal9000/PycharmProjects/Caffe_Experiments_0.6/gather_images.py", line 62, in __init__
    txn.put(str_id.encode('ascii'), serialized_datapoint)
lmdb.MapFullError: mdb_put: MDB_MAP_FULL: Environment mapsize limit reached
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

map size is the maximum size of the whole DB, including metadata - it appears you used the number of expected records.

you increase this number

Comment: This is the first insertion though (see the output on console `Loading 0th image from disk - percentage complete:  0.0 %`.) Also, in this case number of images = 370, and I already made `map_size = num*10 = 370*10 = 3700`.

Comment: the easy way is to use some large value, and later compact the file.
another option is to compute the exact size you need - which is the number of bytes needed for your data and the lmdb overhead.at least for debugging, I would start with the 1st option

Comment: Hi, I am getting an error for full map_size reached. My data is 580 Mb and I have tried allocating 4gb space but still I am getting errror

Comment: same for me, my data is 1.14GB and I allocate 4GB it still does not work

Answer (score 6):

Do you have only 10 bytes per image?

And there is other info except of images in the database. So reserve more space for your LMDB database. For example, this command reserves 1GB (10**9 bytes) for LMDB on your disk drive:

```
env = lmdb.open('image_lmdb', map_size=int(1e9))
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting an error for full map_size reached. My data is 580 Mb and I have tried allocating 4gb space but still I am getting errror

Comment: Just switch over to levelDB SW.

Answer (score 0):

You must use flat terms only, e.g `f(1, 2)` not `f(1, g(2))`.

As [per docs](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus/LMDB-DB_002dSpec-Intro.html):

> Multilevel indexing is not supported, terms have to be “flattened”.